# Android - OpenGL-ES-2.0 alpha blending with ZOrderOnTop

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, alphablending

My problem is the following: I am displaying a GLSurfaceView with ZOrderOnTop set to true and with a simple **Yellow** background.

```
<com.example.MyGLSurfaceView
    android:id="@+id/glid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFF00" /> <!-- yellow background --!>
```

In the MyGLSurfaceView I set up the view as following:

```
setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0);
getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
setPreserveEGL();

setZOrderOnTop(true);
setRenderer(renderer); // variable was initialized
```

What I am trying to achieve is: To animate 2 texture on each other. 1st texture has 1f alpha, the second is animation from 0f to 1f over time (5000 ms in this case). For the simplicity of the example, I made the textures full white (1st) and full black (2nd), both with alpha values 255 in the file.

My `onSurfaceCreated` method (The calls are from the **GLES20** class using static import):

```
@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    glClearColor(1f, 0f, 1f, 1f);// Pink clear color

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    ...
}
```

I set the clear color to **pink** for testing purposes. I'm also using a vertex and fragment shader, which were also loaded in `onSurfaceCreated`. The vertex shader is quite irrelevant in this case (I think) so this is my `fragment shader`:

```
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D u_TextureUnit;
uniform float u_alpha;

varying vec2 v_TextureCoordinates;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_TextureUnit, v_TextureCoordinates);
    gl_FragColor[3] *= u_alpha; 
}
```

I set the alpha value I desire to uniform. The drawing of the objects:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glUniform1f(uAlphaLocation, 0f);
... //drawing white rectangle
glUniform1f(uAlphaLocation, percent);
//percent varies from 0f - 1f based on progress of the animation
... //drawing black rectangle translated right a bit so they overlap
```

I get the following outputs:
At 0f percent:
[image]

Mid-animation: [image]

At 1f percent/End of animation: [image]

You can see the yellow color at the overlap of the 2 rectangle. I guess it comes from the background of the view and has something to do with ZOrderOnTop being true. Color code of the yellow part is **115, 115, 66.** The right part of the 2nd rectangle: **115, 49, 66**

When I use `setZOrderOnTop(false)` and remove the background of the `GLSurfaceView` it just works fine: [image]

I've be trying to use another blending functions but none of them worked correctly.

What I'd like to have, is to have a background for `GLSurfaceView` (obviously I would set clear color to transparent then) and to have a correct alpha blending. Is this achievable? Any help appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is your problem, but be aware that Android uses a premultipled ARGB format for images that is not directly compatible with OpenGL ES alpha blending.  See the third article here http://montgomery1.com/opengl/

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. However my textures in this case have full opacity (255 alpha value) so this can't be the problem.